# I have a sql below, I do not know how to optimize?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT *, SUM(real_premier_num) AS real_premier_num, SUM(premier_num) AS premier_num, 
GROUP_CONCAT(tg_time SEPARATOR '-') AS post_time, GROUP_CONCAT(low_price SEPARATOR '-') 
AS low_price FROM `port_wbinfo` WHERE `city_id` = 12 AND `is_tg` = 0 GROUP BY
`hz_post_id` ORDER BY `off_time` DESC, `shelf_time` DESC, `id` DESC LIMIT 10
```

I created a index like below, but it does not work, I have to group by.

```
alter table port_wbinfo add index `city_tg` (`city_id`,`is_tg`);
```

Comment: Wy are you using `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY`.  That is simply not correct.

Comment: Your query is technically invalid, because you are doing `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` (probably the source of the down votes).  That being said, I'm not sure that an index would help the `GROUP BY` operation, because you are using `SUM` which needs to touch every record anyway.  But you could add indices to the column involved in the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses.

Comment: _"it does not work"_ is not a problem description. Why not? And why are you concerned about optimising? Have you proven that it's performing suboptimally? How long does it take? And by how much is that too slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write the query as:

```
SELECT hz_post_id, SUM(real_premier_num) AS real_premier_num,
       SUM(premier_num) AS premier_num,
       GROUP_CONCAT(tg_time SEPARATOR '-') AS post_time, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(low_price SEPARATOR '-') AS low_price
FROM port_info pi
WHERE city_id = 12
GROUP BY hz_post_id
ORDER BY MAX(id) DESC;
```

`SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` doesn't make sense.  The most recent versions of MySQL -- as with almost all other databases -- would issue an error (with the default settings).

For this query, you can use an index on `port_info(city_id, hz_post_id)`.  If you like, you can add `real_premier_num, premier_num, tg_time, low_price, id` to the index so it covers the query.

This might not produce a major improvement, but a covering index might help.